# How does this template type deduction and overload resolution work?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, argument-dependent-lookup

### Code #1

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename container>
void sort(typename container::iterator beginning,
          typename container::iterator end)
{
    std::cout << "calling custom sorting function\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WpzTaKspNhPKDvMT).

### Code description

It is gonna call the `std::sort` function, which is found by ADL. Though the code below:

### Code #2

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iterator>
void sort(Iterator beginning,
          Iterator end)
{
    std::cout << "calling custom sorting function\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mAAwMQ74MgTctUYd).

Causes ambiguous overload error. So I have two questions:

### Questions

1. How `container` was deduced in code #1?

   From what I know, type deduction during template instantiation cannot backtrack through member types to find the enclosing one (`std::vector<int>` in this case).
2. Even if it could backtrack, why did it compile without causing ambiguous overload error?

Comment: The entire question is based on wrong premises; `container` is not deduced. This is SFINAE.  https://wandbox.org/permlink/OGnCoxCqWapQeRxG

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How `container` was deduced in code #1?

It can't be deduced during template argument deduction because of [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts),

> 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator `::`) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id:

That means your `sort` won't be considered for overload resolution at all, then `std::sort` is called without ambiguity.

Code #2 doesn't have such issue, both your `sort` and `std::sort` are valid candidates then leads to ambiguous overloading error.